# Probability of identical binomial sequences

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I have a pattern consisting of 9 elements which I've found to obey the following rules:

1. Elements 2, 4, 6, 8 are each one of four values (say, A,B,C,D) with equal probability (1/4)
2. Elements 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 are also each one of four values (say, E,F,G,H), but the probabilities of E and H are **non-equal** and binomially derived. e.g., $P_{1:E} = 0.7^2, P_{1:H} = 0.3^2, P_{1:F}=P_{1:G}=0.7*0.3$.

Given the (different) values of $P_{i:x}$ for $i\in\{1,3,5,7,9\}$ and $x \in \{E,F,G,H\}$ (or indeed just $P_{i:E}$, since it's easy to find the binomial $p$ and calculate the rest), how should I calculate the probability of a collision (identical match) between two entire sequences?

It seems clear the even elements can be dealt with after the odd elements simply by dividing by 4^4. But I'd appreciate some guidance on the odd elements.

Example:

$P_{1:E} = 0.7^2, P_{1:H} = 0.3^2, P_{1:F}=P_{1:G}=0.7*0.3$

$P_{3:E} = 0.6^2, P_{3:H} = 0.4^2, P_{3:F}=P_{3:G}=0.6*0.4$

$P_{5:E} = 0.55^2, P_{5:H} = 0.45^2, P_{5:F}=P_{5:G}=0.55*0.45$

$P_{7:E} = 0.4^2, P_{7:H} = 0.6^2, P_{7:F}=P_{7:G}=0.6*0.4$

$P_{9:E} = 0.3^2, P_{9:H} = 0.7^2, P_{9:F}=P_{9:G}=0.3*0.7$